# Is it possible to set up a ganglia cluster with a single node?

Tags: cluster-computing, ganglia

I'm trying to look over some software that normally takes 100+ nodes that uses ganglia to assign and monitor jobs.  I don't have a hundred nodes and DNS is not working at home.  Is it possible for me to set up ganglia with just the one node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can ! I used ganglia some times ago on a single machine. You'll have to install all the ganglia process (gmond and gmetad) on the same machine.
If I remember well, Ganglia will automatically detect your nodes (thanks to gmond heartbeats).

Comment: thanks !  btw is checkjob a feature of ganglia?  that's my next question to post.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I've never heard of such feature, but I only used a small subset of ganglia's features. Good luck